# How to add h2Settings in deployNodes task of Corda?

Tags: deployment, config, h2, corda

I want to add h2 database settings in the Corda deployNodes gradle task. I saw we can specify it using h2Port field. But I want to specify IP/container name instead of localhost.

In node.conf file, it can be achieved

```
h2Settings {
    address: "localhost:12345"
}
```

I also found a way using extraConfig option, but it is not working for other than localhost.

```
extraConfig = ['h2Settings.address' : 'localhost:12345']
```

Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Corda currently does not support the remote H2 database.

The primary use of h2Settings is permitting external access of the h2 database from a remote machine.

More information can be found here: https://docs.corda.net/node-database-access-h2.html#connecting-via-a-socket-on-a-running-node